# PowerBI Desktop: Cumulative of measures from the start of January to Selected Filtered date

Tags: powerbi-desktop, cumulative-sum, measure

I am looking for a way to get a cumulative count using powerBI dax formulas.

I currently have this measure:

```
[Tasks opened] = distinctcount(id number of tasks that are open)
```

When I select the filter month (May 2021), it only shows me the opened tasks in May 2021.

Example - Tasks Opened:
`>`Jan 21 - 5
`>`Feb 21 - 6
`>`Mar 21 - 8
`>`Apr 21 - 2
`>`May 21 - 7
`>`Total = 28

When I select the filter for May 21, I want the measure to show that it is 28 instead of 7, and if I select April 21, I want the measure to show 21.

Help is greatly appreciated! Thank you :)

---

Elaboration:

Basically I want a method where I will be able to filter the tasks opened based on the date selected on the filter.

- When the filter month is May, I want to distinct count the number of incidents that has been open for more than 90 days as of 31 May.
- It should change accordingly when the filter month is April, so it should distinct count incidents that has been open for more than 90 days as of 30 April.
- It should include all the open incidents (whether it is created in Jan/Feb even though the filtered date is April etc).
- I figured it should be like if created date is before filter date, resolution date is after filter date and the incident has been open for more than 90 days, that data should be taken into counter.

--> The issue arise where I cant seem to get the right date for the filter date. Currently I used a measure, but the End of Filtered Date seems to only be the last day of the month (i.e. if filtered month is may, the filtered date will be 31 May 2021).

```
Open incidents = IF(AND(incident_sla[Created]<=[End of Filtered Month],incident_sla[Resolved]>=[End of Filtered Month]),DATEDIFF(incident_sla[Created date],[End of Filtered Month],DAY),0)
```

The sample excel file can be found here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wMLrvfAD1gUUIxljjBgcugJsG4o-w4nE/edit#gid=605277454

P.S. Sorry for the bad formatting, I'm not very familiar with using stack overflow.

Comment: Does this help? https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Cumulative-distinct-count/m-p/507887

Comment: Sample date would help, can you add some sample data?

Comment: Hi @Nick.McDermaid, ive came across that link but it doesnt seem to help.

Comment: Hi @mkRabbani , i couldnt find where to load a file on stackoverflow so ive included it here. Ive also edited the questions to include more specifics. Appreciate any help i can get! :-) https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wMLrvfAD1gUUIxljjBgcugJsG4o-w4nE/edit#gid=605277454